# Linear difference equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can some one, nice and simple, explain me:

1) What are Linear Difference equation?

2) What do we need them for?

3) How do they look?

4) How to you solve them?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Linear difference equations are the discrete counterparts of differential equations. Instead of infinitesimal increments (derivatives), you consider finite ones.

$$a_n u_{n+3}+b_n u_{n+2}+c_n u_{n+1}+d_n u_n=f_n$$

is a linear, non-homogeneous third-order difference equation in $u_n$.

Such equations are solved by techniques similar to those used with ordinary differential equations.

For instance, the homogeneous equation with constant coefficients

$$a u_{n+3}+b u_{n+2}+c u_{n+1}+d u_n=0$$

is solved with a linear combination of exponential terms $r^n$, leading to the characteristic equation

$$ar^3+br^2+cr+d=0.$$

These equations appear for instance in problems such that there is a local relation between neighboring points on a grid.